# How to join 2 models in rails, which are not really in any relationship?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model, relationship

I have 3 models, say Account, Comment and Status. Each Account will have many Comment and Status, but Comment and Status are not in any kind of relationship.

I would like to query the Account's Comment and Status, and sort these comments and status by time. How can I make this?

Thanks all.

Answer (score 1):

You can try to use :through statement:

```
class Comment
  belongs_to :user
  has_many :statuses, :through => :user
end


class Status
  belongs_to :user
  has_many :comments, :through => :user
end
```

And the query:

```
@user = User.first.includes(:comments, :statuses)
```

or

```
@comment = Comment.first.includes(:user, :statuses)
```

or

```
@statuse = Status.first.includes(:user, :comments)
```

Comment: Thanks for reply. But how can I query status and comment at the same time?

Comment: Can you provide mode detailed information about your schema? Also see if updated answer helps

Comment: This help a lot. Let me have some tests tonight. Thanks buddy. :)

Comment: To query status and comments, you mean eager loading? As in `Account.all :include => [:comments, :statuses]`